# Connection PhoneGap with localhost webservice

Tags: android, xml, django, cordova, tastypie

I have a problem connecting with my webserwisem PhoneGap (Django + TastyPie). My PhoneGap - version - 3.3.0.

Calling the POST or GET with plain html - everything is ok The problem starts when I move the project to the emulator - the transfer can not in any way connect. Besides clicking on the link gets "Error loading page".

My xml (res/xml/config.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
       Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
       or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
       distributed with this work for additional information
       regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
       to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
       "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
       with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

         http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

       Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
       software distributed under the License is distributed on an
       "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
       KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
       specific language governing permissions and limitations
       under the License.
-->
<cordova>
    <!--
    access elements control the Android whitelist.
    Domains are assumed blocked unless set otherwise
     -->

    <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*" subdomains="true"/> <!-- allow local pages -->

    <!-- <access origin="https://example.com" /> allow any secure requests to example.com -->
    <!-- <access origin="https://example.com" subdomains="true" /> such as above, but including subdomains, such as www -->
    <!-- <access origin=".*"/> Allow all domains, suggested development use only -->

    <log level="DEBUG"/>
    <preference name="useBrowserHistory" value="false" />
<plugins>
    <plugin name="App" value="org.apache.cordova.App"/>
    <plugin name="Geolocation" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker"/>
    <plugin name="Device" value="org.apache.cordova.Device"/>
    <plugin name="Accelerometer" value="org.apache.cordova.AccelListener"/>
    <plugin name="Compass" value="org.apache.cordova.CompassListener"/>
    <plugin name="Media" value="org.apache.cordova.AudioHandler"/>
    <plugin name="Camera" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher"/>
    <plugin name="Contacts" value="org.apache.cordova.ContactManager"/>
    <plugin name="File" value="org.apache.cordova.FileUtils"/>
    <plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager"/>
    <plugin name="Notification" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification"/>
    <plugin name="Storage" value="org.apache.cordova.Storage"/>
    <plugin name="Temperature" value="org.apache.cordova.TempListener"/>
    <plugin name="FileTransfer" value="org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer"/>
    <plugin name="Capture" value="org.apache.cordova.Capture"/>
    <plugin name="Battery" value="org.apache.cordova.BatteryListener"/>
    <plugin name="SplashScreen" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
</plugins>
<feature name="SplashScreen">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />
</feature>
</cordova>
```

My address to the local web site: 127.0.0.1:8080/further/part/address

Please for help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/> or
<access origin="10.0.2.2" subdomains="true"/>
```

More about it [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses) .

Comment: Unfortunately, both solutions do not work.
In addition, the message "error loading page" - when I click on the link.

Comment: Yes, it works. In methods GET and POST I must put my IP address - front-end side.

Comment: to put up I must have 15 reputation.