# Phonegap Jquery mobile cross domain ajax request not working

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, cross-domain, jsonp

I am trying to make a ajax request from my phonegap app to a serverside code written in php which is on my localhost. I am trying to use the jsonp request. This is my code

```
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/score-tracker/get-groups.php',
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: "application/json",
            async: true,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function(resp){},
            error: function(err) {}
        });
```

But the control does not return either in error or success callbacks. I even have this enabled :

```
$.support.cors = true;
$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
```

WHen i check the request in chrome console, I find the status as "failed" and type as "pending"

This is my server side code :

```
require_once('AddGroup.php');
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$a = json_encode(array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2));
echo $_REQUEST['callback'].'('.$a.')';
```

Please help me. I am really stuck with this.

Thank you

Comment: I think you need to use the actual **IP address** of your localhost instead of **`http://localhost`**. i.e http://<IP address of the server>. If your on windows you can type ipconfig at your DOS (command) prompt to find your IP.

Comment: I tried putting my ip address. Now it shows a 504 gateway timedout error in the console. And when i try to access the url from the browser it says forbidden
http://my-ip/score-tracker/get-groups.php?callback=jQuery19107831414898391813_1405778035154&_=1405778035155

Comment: you need to use a special IP address (10.0.2.2) to connect to your local machine as per the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses). Also have a look at the post over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631908/connection-phonegap-with-localhost-webservice)

Comment: http://10.0.2.2/score-tracker/get-groups.php?callback=jQuery19109905484300106764_1405779312655&_=1405779312656
Still same issue. I get 504 Gateway Time-Out error. I even added the domain to my xml
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>

Comment: @frank I am testing the app on my android device and not on emulator

Comment: Have you tried using the **mobile browser** of the phone for connecting to your local server. How is your mobile connected to the network? I mean are you using a USB cable or wifi or some other method? Can you give details about your network setup? what does `ipconfig` command show in your machine.?

Comment: My phone is connected via the USB. And i run the phonegap cli command to deploy the app onto ma device and then debug it in the chrome console.
I use this command to deploy "phonegap run android" with ma device connected via usb to the lappy

Comment: @frank what additional information do u need?

Comment: do you have a internet connection wifi/broadband? How does your lappy access the internet? You can connect your mobile to the wifi and then type the actual IP address(as seen in ipconfig) of the local machine .

Comment: @frank I use a wifi to connect my lappy to the internet. I tried connecting my mobile to the wifi and then from the mobile browser i typed the actual ip from the ifconfig. It says Forbidden. But if this was the case for my app too, wouldnt the console debuggin in chrome show the forbidden 401 error rather than the 504 error

Comment: when u use the wifi, your request is travelling thru' the internet. i.e request goes out of ur home network on to internet and then connects to your local machine via the internet. So because of the firewall installed on your computer it does not allow any **external connection**. Even though you are trying to connect from you mobile. On the otherhand  when you use your chrome it directory connects to your mobile within ur home network. It does not connect frm the internet. I hope u are able to understand what I am tryin 2 say. U need 2 open ur laptop/router firewall for external connection.

Comment: @frank I think i get your point. But what i am trying to say is that when i connect my phone via usb to the lappy and run. My phone is not on the wifi. It uses its own 3g data connection to make the request to my server. Ryt? (cos I am not using the wifi on my phone when testing). In that case when I am debugging in chrome y doesnt it show a forbidden message rather than a 504 message.

Comment: as I said earlier the chrome browser is directly connecting/talking to your mobile device. Its like a client/server connection without using the internet. They are directly talking to each other, so you do not need a wifi.

Comment: @frank So did u get ma point about the 401 forbidden error? Y is it showing the 504 error rather than the 401

Comment: Please have a look over [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28726/cant-access-tethered-server-from-android-browser-time-out-or-url-blocked) it seems similar to your problem.

Comment: @frank i tried turning off the firewall completely and then making the ajax request.. Still 504 error..

Comment: @frank Thanks for all the help. And the <ip> thing in URL was the one u suggested. And it partially solved the problem.. thanku

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the problem solved. Just posting the answer if any one finds it helpful

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://<ip>/score-tracker/get-groups.php',
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json",
        async: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(resp){},
        error: function(err) {}
    });
```

And in the http.d conf file of apache I had permission denied to the www directoy for which I was getting the forbidden error. I allowed access to that directory and the problem was solved.