# AJAX call not working in Cordova 3.5, but will work when viewed in a browser

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ajax, cordova

I have a fairly frustrating issue with Cordova and an AJAX request that will work when viewed on my desktop/mobile browser, but it simply own't fire from inside the app with Cordova.

My AJAX call is contained in a JS file that I link to from the HTML page, which is this:

```
var DSUser = '4';

var urlLink = 'http://localhost/cwwa/web/app.php/ajax/' + DSUser + '/options/';

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: urlLink,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data) {
        alert('AJAX Works');
        var divsel = $('#divisionSelect');
        divsel.empty();

        var DivisionList = (data.divisions);

        divsel.append('<option value ="0">All Sites</option>');

        $.each(DivisionList, function(i, item){
            divsel.append('<option value ="' + DivisionList[i].division + '">' + DivisionList[i].division + '</option>');
        });

    }
});
```

What this should do is append a lot of options to a HTML dropdown menu. However this doesn't happen. I have added an `alert("works")` inside Success which doesn't fire. So the AJAX call is erroring out.

I added this code to the AJAX call:

```
error: function(req, err){
    console.log(err);
}
```

Which returns the helpful error in Android Studio (interact.js is where the AJAX call is located):

> I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(53)] "error", source:
>   file:///android_asset/www/js/interact.js (53)

I've put the URL in to the browser and it returns the JSON array that I should be expecting. The same AJAX call is used on a website this app will work with, so for the most part the AJAX call itself isn't the issue.

I've read across the internet that you need to give Android permissions to access the Internet. I've included this in my AndroidManifest.xml file also:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Still absolutely no joy with it.

Comment: Are you trying to test using a local machine and Device connected via USB to the local machine? Your statement `urlLink = 'http://localhost/...` makes me assume this. If so than the `localhost` is not visible from the device. There was a similar conversation ( see over [here])(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840771/phonegap-jquery-mobile-cross-domain-ajax-request-not-working#comment38571325_24840771), that I had with another coder, which you can check it out, if it solves your issue.

Comment: Change localhost to ip address

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @frank's comment above, that the most obvious culprit is in your 2nd line, the hostname might not be resolving in the app.

`var urlLink = 'http://localhost/cwwa/web/app.php/ajax/' + DSUser + '/options/';`

After you corrected that, you will need to enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing.

1. In the Cordova `config.xml`, add the following line `<access origin="*" />`.  Reference: [Cordova 3.5.0 Whitelist Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide)
2. On your server, do the following: [I want to add CORS support to my server](http://enable-cors.org/server.html).

Post back with your results.

Comment: What I did as a last ditch attempt to work out what was going on was that I changed the URL to point to a development server held off site. It then worked straight away. I don't think the simulator can use localhost can it?

Comment: Nop, localhost inside the simulator would still point to the phone it is simulating, it can't see your PC. You can use your PC's LAN IP address.

Answer (score 0):

A) Copy and Paste yout App/config.xml to 'App/platforms/browser' and 'App/platforms/browser/www'

or

B) Remove all platforms even browser then create APK using build.phonegap.com

```
'cordova platform remove browser --save'
```

Its working